# How to ask if someone is my attorney?

Tags: attorney-client-privilege

I hired an attorney for a civil matter. Another attorney at the firm has been communicating with me a lot and I find some of the things he says and the questions he asks me odd.

Is there a way I can ask if they are my attorney to be absolutely sure we have an attorney-client relationship?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't think "Are you acting as my attorney, and is this conversation privileged?" is sufficient?  You can also ask your original attorney to confirm, if they are someone you trust more fully.

Comment: @nateeldredge I wanted confirmation an fee to see if there's maybe better language to use.

Answer (score 4):

If you're in the United States, another lawyer in a firm you've hired may or may not be your attorney, but it would not be uncommon for him to have some involvement in the case, and he would be expected to treat you as a client in terms of privilege and conflicts of interest.

Just the same, this is something you need to be very direct on. "Are you my attorney?" or "Have we established an attorney-client relationship?" are going to be your best options.